# Anyone know why i can't load my native libraries?

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library") version "7.2.2"
    kotlin("android") version "1.5.21"

}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.10.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.21")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21")
}

@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
android {
    namespace = "com.aptiv.acf.testinterfaces"
    compileSdk = 31
    ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 31

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets += "MyLibs1_jni"
                targets += "MyLibs2_jni"
                targets += "MyLibs3_jni"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path = project.file("cmakelists/gradle/CMakeLists.txt")
            version = "3.19.0+"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
    }
}
```

When i serached in stackOverFlow people was saying about this code, but i cant even use it:

```
sourceSets.main
{
   jni.srcDirs = [] // ndk-build.cmd needs to be invoked from command line
   jniLibs.srcDirs '/src/main/libs'
}
```

My libs are in the same package like this **build.gradle** in folder libs(*so files) i need help with that, if anyone have any idea i will appreciate that, thanks

Comment: Gradle 7.5.1 and Android studio giraffe

Comment: Are you calling System.loadLibrary() in your Java/Kotlin code? What error does it give you?

Comment: Yes i am, it gives me

Comment: path to my libs and this error: libMyLibs.so: libm.so: ELF load command address/offset not page-aligned, and then at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)

Comment: when i do file on libm.so it gives me: libm.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), static-pie linked, BuildID[md5/uuid]=b1c409b8a8fe08c2c2e7b290733c0f1b, with debug_info, not stripped